# HorizontalPodAutoscaler scales up pods but then terminates them instantly

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, horizontalpodautoscaler

So I have a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` set up for my backend (an fpm-server and an Nginx server for a Laravel application).

The problem is that when the `HPA` is under load, it scales up the pods but it terminates them instantly, not even letting them get into the **Running** state.

The metrics are good, the scale-up behavior is as expected the only problem is that the pods get terminated right after scaling.

What could be the problem?

**Edit:** The same `HPA` is used on the frontend and it's working as expected, the problem seems to be only on the backend.

**Edit 2:** I have `Cluster Autoscaler` enabled, it does it's job, nodes get added when they are needed and then cleaned up so it's not an issue about available resources.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fpm-server
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: fpm
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      layer: fpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        layer: fpm
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}           
      containers:
        - name: fpm
          image: "{{ .Values.fpm.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.fpm.image.tag }}"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          {{- range $name, $value := .Values.env }}
          - name: {{ $name }}
            value: "{{ $value }}" 
          {{- end }}             
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: backend-secrets
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

**hpa.yaml**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: fpm-server-hpa
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: fpm
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: fpm-server
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but infrastructure-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you paste your deployment/statefulset yaml ?

Comment: Have you used https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#configurable-scaling-behavior ?

Comment: Do you have enough resources in the nodes to facilitate the scaled-up Kubernetes pods?

Comment: I have Cluster Autoscaler enabled, it does it's job, nodes get added when they are needed and then cleaned up so it's not an issue about available resources.

Comment: Please check if the code inside the container runs, or the pod just initializing and no commands or purpose for him so he is being terminated automatically. Get logs and events of the pod or deployment and try to understand what exactly causing this. Also, see if there are enough resources for the pod to be running.

Comment: Currently, I have one pod running and it's doing fine, the app is working as intended. I have enough resources on the current node, not even counting the other nodes that the Cluster Autoscaler is creating. About the logs, the HPA logs are saying that it's scaling up to 4 replicas but after their creation, they are terminated as before, nothing else. Logs of the pod look exactly as they should, with the start of the application and the exit when the pods get terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem was with the `replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}` definition. It seems that, if you are using HPA, `replicas` can't be used. I removed this line and the HPA started scaling.